# Big data in pandas, matching and backfilling/forwardfilled one table based on another table

Tags: pandas, group-by, bigdata

I have a dataframe df_original which is huge (10 million rows). The index is date (multiple same dates), and there are 20 rows, but the one of interest here is Company. Company may/may not be available for every date. The data goes back 10 years.

Eg of df_original:

```
           Company
1/24/2007   Astec
1/24/2007   Abra
1/24/2007   Apple
1/24/2007   Acle ltd
1/24/2007   Apple ent
1/24/2007   Aztrazenca
1/24/2007   Alpha ltd
1/24/2007   Altit ltd
1/24/2007   Blackberry
1/24/2007   Burberry
1/24/2007   Blue ltd
1/24/2007   Bluefin
1/25/2017   Abra
1/25/2017   Apple
1/25/2017   Acle ltd
1/25/2017   Aztrazenca
1/25/2017   Altit ltd
1/25/2017   Blackberry
1/25/2017   Burberry
1/25/2017   Blue ltd
1/25/2017   Bluefin
```

Now I have another table which looks like this (in practise it is much larger). It is the dates when a companies grade changes (not daily frequency, just whenever it changes):

df_grade_changes:

```
            Date    Company Grade
2/2/2017    Abra        D
2/1/2017    Blue ltd    B
1/21/2017   Blue fin    C
1/1/2017    Aztrazenca  B
12/10/2016  Altit ltd   A
11/29/2016  Blackberry  C
11/18/2016  Abra        B
11/6/2016   Blue ltd    A
```

I want to add a row in df_original, which has the Grade of each company for each day using df_grade_changes as a source.

Ie, Whenever the Grade changes for a company it to be reflected from that day on wards in df_original. The key thing is that Grades change over time not on a daily manner in df_grade_changes.

Using df_grade_changesin the above example Abra from 11/18/2016 to 1 day before 2/2/2017 would have grade B, for which it will be D after indefinitely unless it arrives at another grade change. So I believe it may have to work from oldest to newest or newest to oldest.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** For the code below to work, you will need to convert the date index in `df_original` to a proper "date" column.

First, perform an "outer" merge on both "company" and "date".

```
df_merge = df_original.merge(df_grade, how='outer', on=["company", "date"])
```

This allows you to add known grade changes from `df_grade_changes` to `df_original` on the correct dates while keeping all data associated with both dataframes.

Next you need to fill unknown grade entries from the last known grade entry by company. It's probably easiest to define a function and use a split-apply-combine approach with Pandas `groupby`.

```
def fill_grades_by_date(data):
    # sort by date in ascending order
    data.sort_values("date", ascending=True, inplace=True)

    # fill unknown "grade" column entries using forward fill method
    data["grade"] = data["grade"].fillna(method="ffill", inplace=False)
    return data

# Implement split-apply-combine on df_merge:
# 1. splits into tables by company
# 2. applies function `fill_grades_by_date`
# 3. combines resulting groups back into a dataframe in the format of `df_merge`
df_result = df_merge.groupby("company").apply(fill_grades_by_date).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) to merge your two DataFrames:

```
# Set Date as the index of df_grade_changes and ensure that it's sorted.
df_grade_changes = df_grade_changes.set_index('Date').sort_index()

# Perform the merge_asof.
df = pd.merge_asof(df_original, df_grade_changes, left_index=True, right_index=True, by='Company')
```

The output using your example data:

```
               Company Grade
2007-01-24       Astec   NaN
2007-01-24        Abra   NaN
2007-01-24       Apple   NaN
2007-01-24    Acle ltd   NaN
2007-01-24   Apple ent   NaN
2007-01-24  Aztrazenca   NaN
2007-01-24   Alpha ltd   NaN
2007-01-24   Altit ltd   NaN
2007-01-24  Blackberry   NaN
2007-01-24    Burberry   NaN
2007-01-24    Blue ltd   NaN
2007-01-24     Bluefin   NaN
2017-01-25        Abra     B
2017-01-25       Apple   NaN
2017-01-25    Acle ltd   NaN
2017-01-25  Aztrazenca     B
2017-01-25   Altit ltd     A
2017-01-25  Blackberry     C
2017-01-25    Burberry   NaN
2017-01-25    Blue ltd     A
2017-01-25     Bluefin     C
```